# Counting solutions to an equation

Tags: number-theory

> Find the number of solutions to $x+y+z = 6$ if $0 \leq z \leq y \leq x$.

Instead of just listing the solutions, I thought of a different way. We know that the total number of solutions to that equation is $\binom{6+2}{2} = \binom{8}{2} = 28$ and then we see that $$\text{#}(x \leq y \leq z) + \text{#}(x \leq z \leq y) + \text{#}(y \leq x \leq z) + \text{#}(y \leq z \leq x) + \text{#}(z \leq y \leq x) + \text{#}(z \leq x \leq y)-5 = 28.$$ Then, since we know $\text{#}(x \leq y \leq z) = \text{#}(x \leq z \leq y) = \text{#}(y \leq x \leq z) = \text{#}(y \leq z \leq x) = \text{#}(z \leq y \leq x) = \text{#}(z \leq x \leq y)$, we solve to get $\text{#}(x \leq y \leq z) = \dfrac{11}{2}+1$, which is not an integer. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Think of 4+1+1, this case appears twice as well.

Comment: @lattice But for different variables.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are substracting 5 at the end because the variable/point $(2,2,2)$ appears in all 6 sets. Now the point $(1,1,4)$ for instance appears twice, in the set $(x \leq y \leq z)$ and in the set $y \leq x \leq z)$

Comment: The same holds for the points $(1,4,1)$ and $(4,1,1)$ and similarly other points such as $(6,0,0)$ appear multiple times. You need to count them all and apply the inclusion exclusion theorem.